I delete google events from google api v3 in nodejs but still can see deleted events. What's wrong?
I am using node-js. There I am trying to remove calendar event. It's successfully. I see that it's marked as deleted but still I can see them on Google Calendar.

await calendar.events.delete({ calendarId: calendarId, eventId: event.id });
let result = await calendar.events.list({ calendarId: calendarId }) - empty
let result = await calendar.events.list({ calendarId: calendarId, showDeleted: true }); I see this event
But in Calendar I see deleted events. It's not removed there

Why I see it there if I removed it successfully? Thanks!

please edit your question and include [example]
